# file upload in html and php not upload in folder

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

I have a problem with uploading my files in my folder. When I run the code I get the message: "File is an image - image/jpeg.Sorry, file already exists.Sorry, your file was not uploaded." But it is'nt a file I uploaded before."

My second problem is that he doesn't put my images in my folder.

This is my uxu.php

```
<div class="overlay-content">
        <form action="../uploadfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="overlay-form">
            <h1>Upload gemaakt werk</h1><br><br>
            <label>Titel</label>
            <input type="text" class="aa-field"><br><br>
            <label>Text</label>
            <textarea rows="4" class="aa-area"> </textarea><br><br>
            <label>Foto</label>
            <input class="aa-file" type="file" name="art_img" id="fileToUpload"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-upload-article" value="Upload">
        </form>
        </div>
```

This is my uploadfile.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "img_upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["art_img"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["art_img"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["art_img"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["art_img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["art_img"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

[This are my folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9SOE.png)

Comment: The code looks like it is doing what it is supposed to.  You might try `if(file_exists($target_file) == false) {`  instead, but it looks legit.

Comment: Yeah. As **Kraang Prime** says, your code does exactly what it is written to perform. It seems that you're confused about all those errors displayed one by one. Better use `die();` in each error block so that you can make sure the script is not running once the condition is failed. Here, you're trying to display all the errors at once. Maybe that's why you see all those errors being displayed.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! The only problem now is that he doesn't put my images in my img_upload folder. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Make sure you have the `img_upload` directory in the same path as your uploadfile.php or you could explicitly tell us your directory structure of your project.

Comment: I added a png to the post with the structure

Comment: I have this same issues and still no solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your error messages one by one with html br element or php exit() / die() function to handle the first error. File_exists, file size and file format verifications are executed outside the post submit condition so you will see the error message even if your form isn't submitted.

For your second problem i think your PHP environment can't find the path, so you need to specify the absolute path.

Change

```
$target_dir = "img_upload/";
```

to

```
$target_dir = __DIR__ . "/img_upload/";
```

Check also the chmod write permissions on the upload directory. 

You can check it with PHP by adding the code  inside your if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  condition :

```
if (!is_writable(dirname($target_file))) {
    exit("Your upload path is incorrect or has no permissions");
}
```

Anyway, you can use this final PHP code  :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $target_dir = __DIR__ . "/img_upload/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["art_img"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["art_img"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".<br>";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        exit("File is not an image.");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    } 
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        exit("Sorry, file already exists.");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["art_img"]["size"] > 500000) {
        exit("Sorry, your file is too large.");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        exit("Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        exit("Sorry, your file was not uploaded.");
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {

        if (is_writable(dirname($target_file))) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["art_img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                exit("The file ". basename( $_FILES["art_img"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.");
            } else {
                exit("Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");
            }
        } else {
            exit("Your upload path is incorrect or has no permissions");
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed it. Now I get the message "File is an image - image/png.
The file wolk2.png has been uploaded.". So that's good, but he still doesn't put it in to my folder.

Comment: There was a little trouble in the final code, change target_dir ... __img_uploasd__ to __img_upload__ then check if the directory /img_upload exists in the directory where your uploadfile.php is placed.

Comment: Yes I changed that. I added a png to the post with my folders.. I think that's alright?